# loopback logout access_token is required

Tags: loopbackjs, angular-loopback

I want to test loopbacks logout endpoint. But it returns access_token is required. what is the correct JSON body to feed or the loopback user logout endpoint?

Comment: It is not immediately clear what you have done and what you are trying to do. Anyway see if my answer helps your problem. If not, Kindly provide me a little more details of your code and/or a screenshot of the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will logout your user.

```
User.logout('asd0a9f8dsj9s0s3223mk', function (err) {
         console.log(err || 'Logged out');
       });
```

[Reference](http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#user-logout)

I assume you aren't setting the access token on the Loopback API Explorer.

You will find this access token section on the top right corner of your API Explorer.

[image: API Explorer]

1. Copy the access token returned by the login API here.
2. Paste it on the accessToken section and click 'Set Access Token'
3. Try calling the logout API now

**UPDATE**

To call from a client. Add the Access token as a query parameter or header.

```
ACCESS_TOKEN=6Nb2ti5QEXIoDBS5FQGWIz4poRFiBCMMYJbYXSGHWuulOuy0GTEuGx2VCEVvbpBK

# Authorization Header
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
http://localhost:3000/api/widgets

# Query Parameter
curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/widgets?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN
```

[Reference](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Making-authenticated-requests.html)

Comment: I want to test it from a client. Not from the api explorer

Comment: Updated the answer to test from client.